# swal().then(function ()) not firing in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sweetalert2

Hoping you can help me with this, I assume there is a small thing I am missing.

My `_layout.cshtml` contains all the relevant scripts to have sweetheart working on IE:

(this was working in previous versions though we haven't had to support IE for some time)

```
@if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer")
{
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/es6-promise@3.2.1"></script>
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/bower_components/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<!--[if IE 9]>
    <script src="~/bower_components/sweetalert2-ie9/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

As you can see, promise is included before `sweetalert2` and I know that this is fine as the sweetalert functions on my form submit.

The issue is that when I click "Yes" the `.then()` function is not being hit, in debugger it is ignored and skipped straight over. This is only relevant to IE, only tested in 11 at the moment I am just going to check other versions now. I cannot work out why this is happening, any ideas?

Relevant .js:

```
vm.PostCommentData = function (postData, event) {
    var $commentTextBoxId = '#' + vm.createRemedyCommentId;

    if ($($commentTextBoxId).length) {
        var globalTranslations = globalDashboard.GetTranslations();

        swal({
            title: translations.AreYouSureYouWantToSubmit,
            text: '',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: '<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> ' + globalTranslations.Yes,
            cancelButtonText: '<i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> ' + globalTranslations.No,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
            buttonsStyling: false
        }).then(function () {
            vm.state($(event.currentTarget).data('state'));
            var newComment = $($commentTextBoxId).val();
            var errorMessage = $("<ul class='list-unstyled' />");
            var hasErrored = false;

            if (vm.selectedQuestions().length == 0) {
                errorMessage.append("<li>" + translations.AtLeastAQuestionIsRequiredToBeSelected + "</li>");
                hasErrored = true;
            }

            if (vm.selectedDealershipId() == undefined) {
                errorMessage.append("<li>" + translations.PleaseSelectADealership + "</li>");
                hasErrored = true;
            }

            if (newComment === '') {
                errorMessage.append("<li>" + translations.CommentTextIsRequired + "</li>");
                hasErrored = true;
            }

            if (hasErrored) {
                swal({
                    title: translations.Warning,
                    html: errorMessage,
                    type: 'error',
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    confirmButtonText: '<i class="fas fa-check"></i> ' + globalTranslations.OK,
                    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success'
                });
            }
            else {

                var successMessage = translations.YourRemedyHasBeenSubmitted;
                if (vm.selectedQuestions().length > 1)
                    successMessage = translations.YourRemediesHaveBeenSubmitted;

                swal({
                    title: translations.Completed,
                    text: vm.globalViewModel().decodeEntities(successMessage),
                    type: 'success',
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    confirmButtonText: '<i class="fas fa-check"></i> ' + globalTranslations.OK,
                    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success'
                }).then(function () {
                    $(remedyBoxId + " .overlay").show();
                    $('#create-remedy-commentFormId').submit();
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`vm.` is `knockout.js` bound but I am almost completely certain knockout has no part to play in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of poking around, I realised that this needs a polyfill service.

My IE tags were updated to:

```
@if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer")
    {
        <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/es6-promise@3.2.1"></script>
    }
```

Gotta love the 1 line fixes!

Comment: Just adding a link to the popular polyfill: https://github.com/github/fetch